# D3 Pie Chart too dented

Tags: asp.net-mvc, d3.js

I am getting as a result a badly rendered pie chart. Why is this happening? Am I doing smth wrong? What can I do to have a better border? I am corrently using v3.5.17.

[image: Pie chart too dented]

```
var w = 500,
            h = 500;

            //var data = [10, 80, 50, 60, 30, 42, 27, 77];

            var max = d3.max(data);
            var min = d3.min(data);

            var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

            console.log(color(50));

            var canvas = d3.select("#piegraphic").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);


            var group = canvas.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(200, 200)");

            var r = 150;

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(r - 10)
                .innerRadius(0);

            var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(r + 10)
                .innerRadius(0);


            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .value(function (d) {
                    return d.count;
                });

            var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

            var asdf = arcs.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("fill", function (d) {
                    return color(d.data);
                })


            asdf.on("mouseover", function (d) {
                d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).attr("d", arc2);
            });

            asdf.on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
                d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).attr("d", arc);
            });

            var circle = group.append("circle")
                .attr({
                    "cx": 0,
                    "cy": 0,
                    "r": 140,
                    "fill": "none",
                    "stroke": "#fff",
                    "stroke-width": 2
                });
```

I tried other approaches but I always getting the same result I dont know what else I can try. Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
My data looks like this :

```
[{count:106136313.3, label : "RR" },{count:136313.3, label : "RA" },{count:1061313.3, label : "TE" }]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, the chart is rendering ok for me, changing `d.count` to `d`: https://jsfiddle.net/bcv8t469/

Comment: Oh I see. Do you have an idea of why the pie I see on my end looks like the one on the image? The border does not look good.

Comment: It's strange. Did you uncomment the `data` and change `d.count` for `d`? Also, what is `piegraphic`? Is it a div? What are the sizes and the positioning?

Comment: yes. Well my data is an array of json object. But I tried the approach you shared and looks the same

Comment: So, please share you data structure editing your question (just a little bit of it, it doesn't need to be all the data if it is too big).

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: It seems alright to me: https://jsfiddle.net/bw22npLb/ I just changed the colors for `d.data.label`, mapped the domain for the colors and changed back the pie function. I don't know why the chart is that way in your end. PS: your data has three slices, but one of them is less than 1% of total, and will not show up.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. This is a real headache